# datetimeindex subset of another?

Tags: pandas

What is the fastest way to check if a pandas DateTimeIndex is entirely a subset of another?

I am looking at comparing the intersection of the 2 indexes with the smaller one: first the length, and then the contents.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would do:

```
index_1 = pd.date_range('1/1/2016', periods=100, freq='H')
index_2 = pd.date_range('1/3/2016', periods=15, freq='H')
set(index_2).issubset(index_1)
```

or:

```
set(index_1).issuperset(index_2)
```

Comment: If this test is performance sensitive, do we expect a negligible cost to transform the index to a python set and then call issubset on that?

Comment: yes there is, `%timeit` shows this method being directly slower to the length of the indices, see Igor Raush's answer (IMHO him's should be the accepted answer)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to [valtuarte's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35657246/1391671) is to use the built-in `DatetimeIndex.intersection` method:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
one = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=72, freq='H')
two = pd.date_range('1/2/2011', periods=12, freq='H')

# either...
np.all(one.intersection(two) == two)

# ...or
one.intersection(two).equals(two)
```

This solution is significantly faster for large indices (the test below is with 720k and 120k periods):

```
In [10]: %timeit set(one).issuperset(two)
1 loops, best of 3: 992 ms per loop

In [11]: %timeit np.all(one.intersection(two) == two)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.8 ms per loop

In [12]: %timeit one.intersection(two).equals(two)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.77 ms per loop
```

**EDIT** Added alternative (marginally faster) way to compare `Index` equality.

Comment: Yes, in my system that was about 15x faster for a (3M, 0.5M) length indices.

Comment: if the intersection is empty, does the above still works?
or do we need explicit test on the length of the intersection first?

Comment: Yes, an empty intersection will be an empty `DatetimeIndex` which will not compare equal to either of the original ranges.